# ExpressJS/AngularJS : Converting JSON Object to String

Tags: json, angularjs, express, mongoose, meanjs

I'm struggling with something that might be very easy, but hours of searching on Stackoverlow haven't helped.

I'm using Sir Trevor with MEANJS.  Sir Trevor applies itself against a textarea field and saves its content as a JSON String.

Sir Trevor is saving its content to a field `Content`, which is set as an `Object` type in a Mongoose schema.

Creating works great and everything saves as expected.

However, when editing, the data doesn't come up correctly.  The textfield is assigned `data-ng-model="article.content"` [the 'content' field from the model], but displays as `[object Object]`, so when Sir Trevor tries to parse the value, it errors out.

I've tried using a directive with `$formatters` to change the value:

```
    <textarea data-ng-model="article.content" id="content" 
class="form-control st-instance" placeholder="Content" stRaw>
</textarea>
```

...and here is the directive:

```
articleApp.directive('stRaw', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

        function stringIt(val) {
            return JSON.stringify(val);
        }

        ngModel.$formatters.push(stringIt);

    }
};
```

});

But it doesn't seem like the directive is ever triggered [I tried `console.log` within the link function and never saw anything].

I was able to make it work fine before by changing the schema type `String` and then using `stringify` over and over again within the code.  This seemed sloppy, created undue bloat and also created challenges when trying to iterate through on an actual view page [it was seen as a `String` -- couldn't figure out how to parse].

I'm assuming I need to somehow catch the `article.content` attribute before it's rendered and change the value to a string. Is that the right direction?

Comment: can you give us a console.log(article.content)

Comment: @ma08 - doing a console.log(article.content) on the server-side code [finding the article based on id] returns "{ data: 
   [ { data: [Object], type: 'heading' },
     { data: [Object], type: 'text' } ] }"  ... but, running the same console.log from the angular side [in the code used to populate the edit screen], it comes back undefined.

Comment: and on the client side?

Comment: Hi @ma08 - I hit enter too soon, so had to edit my reply. =)  Running console.log(article.content) within the code where I set $scope.article to the found article from the server-side query results in undefined.  Inspecting $scope in firebug shows content is populated with an object with the expect key:value pairs.

Comment: If it makes any difference, the rest of the fields display correctly -- title, slug, tags, etc.  It's really just this block I'm having challenges with.

Comment: can you put the code where you are making the server call from the frontend(angular) and assigning data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is typo in your html, the `stRaw` should be `st-raw`.

```
<textarea data-ng-model="article.content" id="content" class="form-control st-instance" placeholder="Content" st-raw></textarea>
```

Comment: Sheesh -- I hate it when I overlook such a simple thing. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome :) I frustrated with this kind of problems very so often myself, when I start to learn angularjs.